# Почему после сборке буст, отсутсвуют некоторые библиотеки?

Tags: c++, библиотеки, boost, сборка

Я хочу подключить boost.asio, но после сборки boost в папке lib отсутствует бинарный файл данной библиотеки. Как это исправить? (ниже список всех бинрных файлов в папке)

```
libboost_atomic.a              libboost_math_tr1l.so
libboost_atomic.so             libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.74.0
libboost_atomic.so.1.74.0      libboost_math_tr1.so
libboost_chrono.a              libboost_math_tr1.so.1.74.0
libboost_chrono.so             libboost_nowide.a
libboost_chrono.so.1.74.0      libboost_nowide.so
libboost_container.a           libboost_nowide.so.1.74.0
libboost_container.so          libboost_prg_exec_monitor.a
libboost_container.so.1.74.0   libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so
libboost_context.a             libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.74.0
libboost_context.so            libboost_program_options.a
libboost_context.so.1.74.0     libboost_program_options.so
libboost_contract.a            libboost_program_options.so.1.74.0
libboost_contract.so           libboost_random.a
libboost_contract.so.1.74.0    libboost_random.so
libboost_coroutine.a           libboost_random.so.1.74.0
libboost_coroutine.so          libboost_regex.a
libboost_coroutine.so.1.74.0   libboost_regex.so
libboost_date_time.a           libboost_regex.so.1.74.0
libboost_date_time.so          libboost_serialization.a
libboost_date_time.so.1.74.0   libboost_serialization.so
libboost_exception.a           libboost_serialization.so.1.74.0
libboost_fiber.a               libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.a
libboost_fiber.so              libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.so
libboost_fiber.so.1.74.0       libboost_stacktrace_addr2line.so.1.74.0
libboost_filesystem.a          libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.a
libboost_filesystem.so         libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.so
libboost_filesystem.so.1.74.0  libboost_stacktrace_backtrace.so.1.74.0
libboost_graph.a               libboost_stacktrace_basic.a
libboost_graph.so              libboost_stacktrace_basic.so
libboost_graph.so.1.74.0       libboost_stacktrace_basic.so.1.74.0
libboost_iostreams.a           libboost_stacktrace_noop.a
libboost_iostreams.so          libboost_stacktrace_noop.so
libboost_iostreams.so.1.74.0   libboost_stacktrace_noop.so.1.74.0
libboost_locale.a              libboost_system.a
libboost_locale.so             libboost_system.so
libboost_locale.so.1.74.0      libboost_system.so.1.74.0
libboost_log.a                 libboost_test_exec_monitor.a
libboost_log_setup.a           libboost_thread.a
libboost_log_setup.so          libboost_thread.so
libboost_log_setup.so.1.74.0   libboost_thread.so.1.74.0
libboost_log.so                libboost_timer.a
libboost_log.so.1.74.0         libboost_timer.so
libboost_math_c99.a            libboost_timer.so.1.74.0
libboost_math_c99f.a           libboost_type_erasure.a
libboost_math_c99f.so          libboost_type_erasure.so
libboost_math_c99f.so.1.74.0   libboost_type_erasure.so.1.74.0
libboost_math_c99l.a           libboost_unit_test_framework.a
libboost_math_c99l.so          libboost_unit_test_framework.so
libboost_math_c99l.so.1.74.0   libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.74.0
libboost_math_c99.so           libboost_wave.a
libboost_math_c99.so.1.74.0    libboost_wave.so
libboost_math_tr1.a            libboost_wave.so.1.74.0
libboost_math_tr1f.a           libboost_wserialization.a
libboost_math_tr1f.so          libboost_wserialization.so
libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.74.0   libboost_wserialization.so.1.74.0
```

Comment: [By default, Boost.Asio is a header-only library.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html#boost_asio.using.optional_separate_compilation)

Comment: @user7860670 можно перенести это в ответ, хоть и короткий